# reading integers in a line without using list data type in python-3.x

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying solve this problem(https://www.codechef.com/problems/AMR15A)
without using list data type like we can do it in cpp . Or I want to know how to stop scanning until a space is encountered for int data type or string data type . Is there a way

Answer (score 0):

To my current Knowledge if you want to access the number of weapons by each soldier you have to store it as a List in one way or the other and later you can scan the list using indexing.

If you are thinking of taking the input as a string and then converting it to numbers while scanning I would suggest you to not go for this option since there is a high probability that for a large data set it will surpass the time limit of 1 sec.